# After update OS X EI Capitan, external hard disk format changed

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ntfs

I always use the same external hard disk on my Mac formatted as OS X Extended (Journaled). After upgrading my OS, it's recognized as NTFS volume now.

What should I do?

Comment: This is impossible.  Upgrading to El Capitan most certainly won't change a hard drive format, especially to a format that is a Microsoft one.  Are you sure that it wasn't NTFS to begin with?

Comment: Please add a screenshot and the output of `diskutil info /dev/disk1` entered in Terminal.app. Depending on your internal disk and the number of external disks attached you may have to replace disk1 by disk2 or disk3.

Comment: I have to agree that this does not sound very likely. But without any further information it is difficult to come up with an answer

Answer (score 1):

If what you say is true (and I must say, it sounds *extremely* unlikely), then your only options really are:

- EITHER Copy all the data from the external drives, and then reformat them as HFS+ (journaled) and copy the data back.
- OR Leave them as they are.

There really is not much else you can do with them.